# UISearchController search result cell background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

My `UISearchController` displays search results in `UITableViewCell`s with background colour that I have not set

[image]

I can see by debugging the views that this grey colour is that of the `cell.contentView`. However, it doesn't react to me setting

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Are there any other **methods to override** that strange grey colour?

Comment: did you try `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`?

Comment: Yes, same non-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to provide an example project that reproduces your scenario? What does the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` look like? If so, we can probably be much more helpful in determining the issue.

Without knowing specifics, it might be worth trying to set the contentView's backgroundColor in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, which occurs a bit later than `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

It may also be worth making your own subclass of `UITableViewCell` so that you can better control the coloring of the cell.

Comment: The thing is, I am using my own subclass of `UITableViewCell`, but it seems that iOS overrides the `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` at some point. However, setting the latter to `[UIColor whiteColor]` in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` did the trick for me - thank you for the suggestion.